# Determine all pairs $(a,b)$ of positive integers such that $ab^2+b+7$ divides $a^2b+a+b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Determine all pairs $(a,b)$ of positive integers such that $ab^2 + b + 7$ divides $a^2b + a +b$.

I guess the trivial solution is $a=b=7$.
Also any $a$ and $b$ which are divisible by $7$ will seem to suit.
we can also write
$b(\frac{a}{b}+1+\frac{7}{b}) \cdot x=a\cdot(ab+1+\frac{b}{a})$
From where all $a, b$ that satisfy: $\frac{b^2}{a}=7$ and $a>b$, are OK.

Is my solution full and complete? Are there any other solutions?

Comment: (I am not promoting another site) but if you surf [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/) you can easily find a lot of solution on this problem. [Their is also a section called Contest problem, where IMO problems were solved and categorized year-wise] :)

Comment: @MANMAID I am interested in discussion, explanation etc. The website U proposed lacks this

Comment: well..., that's true. I just said if you want the solution, then...

Comment: "any $a$ and $b$ which are divisible by $7$ will seem to suit" ? Do you mean that every pair $(a/b)$ with $7|a$ and $7|b$ is a solution ?

Comment: @Peter dunno. I suggested that any 7|a and 7|b, but now, after thinking twice, that doesn't seem that way

Comment: Seems that one family of solutions is $$(7k^2/7k)$$ where $k$ is a positive integer and besides these solutions, I only found the pairs $(11/1)$ and $(49/1)$

Comment: $(11/1)$ and $(49/1)$ are the only solutions I found NOT belonging to the family. Did I use the word "besides" wrong ?

Comment: @Peter can U show it?

Comment: @NiHao92 AoPS is a forum so you certainly can discuss the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$%%ab^2 + b + 7 \ | \ a^2b + a + b$$

We know that:

$$ 
ab^2 + b + 7 \ | \ a(ab^2 + b + 7) 
= 
a^2b^2+ab+7a 
; 
$$

$$ 
ab^2 + b + 7 \ | \ b(a^2b + a + b) 
= 
a^2b^2+ab+b^2 
; 
$$

so we can conclude 
$$ 
ab^2 + b + 7 \ | \ 
\Big[ 
 a(ab^2 + b + 7) - b(a^2b + a + b) \Big] 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
\Longrightarrow
\\ 
ab^2 + b + 7 \ | \ 
\Big[ 
 (a^2b^2+ab+7a) - (a^2b^2+ab+b^2) \Big] 
\Longrightarrow
\\ 
ab^2 + b + 7 \ | \ 
7a - b^2 
\ \ \ \ \
\color{Blue}{\star} 
$$

---

---

---

**First case**: 
$7a-b^2=0$; which implies that there exists an integer $n$; such that: 
$$(a,b)=(7n^2,7n);$$ 
one can check that $(a,b)=(7n^2,7n)$ satisfies in;
the divisibility condition $ab^2 + b + 7 \ | \ a^2b + a + b$.

**Second case**: 
$0 < 7a-b^2 $; 
note that 
$\color{Red}{0} < (b+\dfrac{1}{2})^2+\dfrac{27}{4} = \color{Red}{b^2+b+7}$,
so in this case we have: 
$$ 
ab^2 + (b + 7) < |ab^2 + b + 7| < 7a-(b^2) 
\Longrightarrow 
\\ 
ab^2 + \color{Red}{0} 
< 
ab^2 + \color{Red}{(b^2 + b + 7)} < 7a 
\Longrightarrow 
ab^2 < 7a 
\Longrightarrow 
\\ 
b^2 < 7 
\Longrightarrow 
b=1 
\ \ 
\text{or} 
\ \ 
b=2 
. 
$$

- If $b=1$; then by replacing in $\color{Blue}{\star}$ 
  we get: 
  $a + 8 \ | \  7a - 1 $,
  on the otherhand we have: 
  $a + 8 \ | \  7(a + 8) $,
  so we can conclude that 
  $a + 8 \ | \  57 $,
  which gives us the two posibilities $a=11$ and $a=49$;
  one can check that each of the pairs  $(a,b)=(11,1)$ and $(a,b)=(49,1)$ satisfies the divisibility condition.
- If $b=2$; then by replacing in $\color{Blue}{\star}$ 
  we get: 
  $4a + 9 \ | \  7a - 4 \ | \  4(7a - 4) = 28a - 16 $,
  on the otherhand we have: 
  $4a + 9 \ | \  7(4a + 9) = 28a + 63 $,
  so we can conclude that 
  $4a + 9 \ | \  79 $,
  which does not gives us any posibilities for $a$.
  [Note that $79$ is a prime number.]

**Third case**: 
$7a-b^2 < 0$; 
note that in this case $0 < a$,
so we have: 
$$ 
ab^2 + b + 7 < |ab^2 + b + 7| < b^2-7a 
\Longrightarrow 
\\ 
\color{Red}{0} < 
(a-1) 
\Bigg[ b + \dfrac{1}{2(a-1)} \Bigg]^2 
+ 
(7a-\dfrac{1}{4(a-1)}+7)
= 
(ab^2 + b + 7) + 
(7a-b^2) 
< \color{Red}{0} 
; 
$$
which is an obvious $\color{Red}{\text{contradiction}}$; so there is no solution in this case.

---

So the solutions are as follows:
$$ 
(11,1), \ (49,1) 
\ \ \text{and} \ \ 
(7n^2,7n) 
\ \ \text{for any} \ \ 
n \in \mathbb{N} 
. 
$$

Comment: so we can conclude, in the beginning.. could U please elaborate on this, write it more verbously?

Comment: @NiHao92 ; $ab^2 + b + 7$ divides both of the 
$a(ab^2 + b + 7)$ and $b(a^2b + a + b)$;  
so it must divides their difference:  
$a(ab^2 + b + 7)-b(a^2b + a + b)=(a^2b^2+ab+7a)-(a^2b^2+ab+b^2)=7a-b^2$.  Are you ok now?

Comment: yeah, now I get it. But still, the equality sign afterwards is a bit misleading

Comment: @NiHao92 ; yes you are right i will edit it.

Comment: could U also write the second case more verbously, cuz, unlike case 1 and case 3, I still didn't grasp it

Comment: @NiHao92 ; I have edited a bit; please refresh your page. Where is your difficulty by **second case**. Does the problem lies before the 2 sub-cases?

Comment: above. I don't understand where did U get $0 < (b+\dfrac{1}{2})^2+\dfrac{27}{4} = b^2+b+7$ from, and until subcases

Comment: @NiHao92 $
\color{Blue}{ab^2} + \color{Red}{0} 
< 
ab^2 + \color{Red}{(b^2 + b + 7)} < \color{Blue}{7a} 
\Longrightarrow 
ab^2 < 7a $; Did you get it now? Does it solves your problem?

Comment: I have no problem with this sub-part. I just don't understand $|ab^2 + b + 7| < 7a-(b^2)$. I mean, intuitively I get it, but how to describe that logically?

Everything that follows I understand in case 2

Comment: @NiHao92 ; Let $A$ be a positive integer, also let $B$ be an integer; such that $\color{Blue}{B \mid A}$. This means there exists a  $\color{Red}{\text{non-zero}}$ integer $k$ such that $kB=A$. We know that $\color{Blue}{1 \leq |k|}$; so we can conclude that $|B|=\color{Blue}{1}. |B| \leq \color{Blue}{|k|}.|B|=|A|=A$, so we have :   $\color{Blue}{|B| \leq A}$; Does it solves your problem?

Comment: thanx, got it. And the last hard part:
$0 < 
(a-1) 
\Bigg[ b + \dfrac{1}{2(a-1)} \Bigg]^2 
+ 
(7a-\dfrac{1}{4(a-1)}+7)$

from where did U get this representation of $(ab^2 + b + 7) + 
(7a-b^2)$ ? I understand that everything correct here, and I fully comprehend the solution, but how did U invent it, what was your logical pathway?

Comment: @NiHao92 ; It gives us the contradiction $0<0$; which implies there is no solution in this case; and about your another question "from where did U get this representation" ; only notice that we have $Ax^2+Bx+c= A\Bigg[ x+\dfrac{B}{2A} \Bigg]^2+(C-\dfrac{B^2}{4A})$; Does it helps?

Comment: thanx. I just was asking in order to get some techniques I could employ 4 myself when I'll be solving other tasks

Comment: I don't know if someone told you this already, but it's not necessary to use colours in posts.

Comment: @Xam ; My dear Xam, you are right, it's not neccessary. For example have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407714/show-that-for-any-integer-n-ge-6-the-inequality-2n7n-holds/2407722#2407722 ; to me; it seems that I explain it live; and using all my ablilities; such as body language; or both my hands to explain more and to understand the main points in one glimpse. Sometimes I used to use colors to emphasis; But all of them is my opinion; however usually people says to me that using colors help them to understand more.

Answer (score 4):

First we will dealt with the cases when $b=1,2,3,4,5,6$ and then we can assume that $b \geq 7$,

For the case $b=1$ we get that $a+8 | a^2+a+1$ which means $a(a+8) +r = a^2+a+1$  and we want $r=0 \mod a+8$ so solving the above gives that $r = 1 - 7 a$ so we want that $a+8|1-7a$ which means that $-7(a+8)+r = 1-7a$ and we want $r=0 \mod a+8$ so solving the above gives that $r = 57 \mod a+8$.

Now $57=3*19$ so $3=0 \mod a+8$ or $19 = 0 \mod a+8$ or $57 = 0 \mod a+8$ solving these equations yields that $(11,1)$ and $(49,1)$ are solutions.

Doing the same for $b=2,3,4,5,6$ yields that there are no solutions.

Now we can assume $b \geq 7$, also $a \geq b \geq 7$, because if we let $a< b$ and $a b^2 +b +7 < a^2 b+a+b$ we will get contradiction arriving at $a \geq b-\frac{1}{7}$ and since $a,b$ are integers we get that $a\geq b$.

Divide the equation by $a b$ we get that $(b+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{7}{ab})x = a+\frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b}$ which is just $ b x +\frac{x}{a}+ \frac{7x}{ab} = a+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$

Now we know that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} \leq \frac{2}{7}<1$ so assuming that $\frac{x}{a}+ \frac{7x}{ab} <1$ we must have that $a = b x$ substituting that we get that $b=7x$ so $a = b x = 7x x = 7x^2$ for all $x \geq 1$.

Now, what if $\frac{x}{a}+ \frac{7x}{ab}\geq y \geq 1$ we get that $a= b x+y$ substituting we get that $\frac{7 x}{b (b x+y)}+\frac{x}{b x+y}+b x = \frac{1}{b x+y}+b x+\frac{1}{b}+y$  which is $\frac{7 x}{b (b x+y)}+\frac{x}{b x+y}-\frac{1}{b x+y}-\frac{1}{b}-y=0$ solving for $x$  we get that $x =\frac{-b y^2-b-y}{b^2 y-7}$ Now since $b \geq 7 $ and $y \geq 1$ the denominator is non-negative and the numerator is negative so $x$ is **negative** which is contradiction thus,

the solutions $(11,1),(49,1),(7x^2,7x)$ for all $x\geq 1$ are the only solutions.